# JQuery: Autofilling multiple contenteditables with classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a website that needs a table. Some of the blocks are the same so they can be auto-filled. However, I am not able to figure out how to autofill these blocks.

getelementsbyclassname always seems to return undefined as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".block-e").on('keyup',function(){
  var fill = $(".block-e").innerHtml
  alert(fill)
    $(".block-e").text(fill);
  });
});
```

The table and the code I've tried is at a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jinsong04/zb4aofp2/1/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close, however some changes are needed:

- consider adding `.not(this)` prior to updating the text of `.block-e` elements via `.text(value)`. Doing that ensures all `.block-e` elements are updated, except for the one that is triggering the actual `keyup` event. Without this, the `keyup` event will cause a read and write to the cell being edited which will cause unexpected editing behavior
- as cells in your table are being edited via `contentEditable`, you should obtain the current `value` of the block being edited via `.text()` rather than `innerHTML`

In code, these changes can be applied like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".block-e").on('keyup',function(){

    var value = $(this).text();

    $(".block-e").not(this).text(value);
  });
});
```

Here's a [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a7mrk1qb/) as well. Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry for the late check but this worked! Thank you!